# WEB приложение. с чего начать

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте.

Этот пост не преследует цель разжигания религиозных войн :)

Имеющийся опыт:
Программирование на dot NET (C#), реализовано несколько больших проектов. В общей сложности 7 лет опыта разработки.
На данный момент изучаю (неспешно) С++ QT (но это так, для души).
Очень хочется писать web-приложения, но не сайты, а именно приложения с динамическим UI.

В то время, как с декстопным программированием все ясно, берешь компилятор, ide, ui-framework, куришь документацию и погнал... Для web не могу разобраться в плоть до того, на каком языке стоит писать... 
Сначала взялся за php, потом насоветовали java ee. Пока на лоре подбирал ui для java ee, открыл для себя Angular.
В общем, в голове каша.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой правильный путь для разработки web приложений с ui выбрать? Какая IDE в данном «пути» будет актуальна? Какой язык программирования выбрать? На чем писать ui? 
И что вообще на рынке web-приложений сейчас актуально?
Спасибо.

Comment: если есть опыт работы с [tag:C#] то можно посмотреть на [tag:asp.net-mvc]. свое знакомство я начинал вот [здесь](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/). вопрос скорее всего закроют как слишком общий

Comment: Честно говоря, хотелось бы слезть с иглы microsoft.

Comment: *и подсесть на другую иглу* :) а если серьезно то чем конкретно вы хотите заниматься в вебе: пользовательская/серверная часть?

Comment: Все пути правильные и все находят свои собственные.

Comment: Самый правильный путь - бекенд на Go, фронтенд - Angular2 (TypeScript).

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев В чём отличие веб-приложения от сайта?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Чего вы решили, что есть "самый правильный путь"?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov личный опыт

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если только начали изучать веб, тогда первое что надо осознать, что в вебе есть две части: сервер (backend) и клиент (frontend), которые друг про друга в обще ничего не знают, и на изучение каждой уходят годы. Поэтому нужно понять кем вы хотите работать full stack программистом который должен владеть и тем, и тем либо профильно backend или frontend разработчиком.  Для этого выбора могу посоветовать проанализировать hh.ru на предмет востребованности специалистов. Лично мое мнение full stack программистом развиваться не стоит так как в вебе сейчас очень много всего и выучить это мозгов не хватит, а при устройстве на работу как правило требуют детальных навыков по каждой из частей.

Но первое с чего нужно начать: с изучения html разметки, базово разобраться что такое http протокол, что такое веб сервер, как веб сервер общается с браузером. Дальше можно взяться за изучение либо backend либо frontend части.

Языки программирования различаются только на бекенде: php, asp.net, java, python, ruby on rails, node js. При выборе нужно опять же посмотреть в каких компаниях у себя в городе вы хотите работать и что они используют.

На фронтенде нужно учить

1)  css - часть которая отвечает за оформление страницы

2)  javascript - это интерпретатор который отрабатывает в браузере, за счет которого достигается динамика страницы без ее перезагрузки.

Но если решите идти в сторону frontend разработки нужно учесть несколько нюансов:

1)  Обе эти технологии могут по-разному отрабатывать в разных браузерах, поэтому придётся писать код под все (конечно могут встретиться проекты только под chrome, но на это рассчитывать не стоит)

2)  С каждым днем возрастает требование к адаптивности, то есть нужно чтобы приложение одинаково хорошо работало под разные виды устройств (компьютеры, планшеты, сотовые и так далее) для этого нужны дополнительные навыки.

3)  Бешенное сообщество, огромное количество Фреймворков и всяких приблуд которые еще не вышли, а все уже хотят их использовать (ну и старые конечно знать надо). Вот статья на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/312022/ но она не шуточная, все так как там написано.

Backend навыки все-таки более статичны.

IDE для каждой технологии своя, на фронтенде лично я использую microsoft visual studio for web express.

Главное, что стоит понять, что период, между тем как вы начнете изучать веб и тем как вам начнут платить деньги коротким не будет. Поэтому думайте и определяйтесь, желаю удачи в ваших начинаниях!

Comment: front-end выбирайте такой, для которого сами сможете относительно легко делать/править компоненты. Всегда приходится сталкиваться с тем, что среди библиотечных что-то работает не так или вообще нет ничего подходящего.

Comment: и все конторы в которых вы будите работать сразу под вас подстроятся)))

Comment: Если речь идёт о работе в какой-то конторе, то и выбора с чего начинать в принципе не может быть, Когда сам себе контора, то осваивать нужно то, с чем быстрее разберёшься от и до.

Answer (score 0):

Ну java не плохая вещь особенно для больших проектов. Я думаю все по вашему вкусу.

- java, особенно хорошо сочетается с Spring Framework есть так же и для .NET платформ
- Node.JS, если хотите писать на JavaScript (Набирает обороты в последнее время)
- PHP, можно было не бросать

Советую для front-end Angular2.

### IDE

Кому как и кто к чему привык но лично для меня продукты от JetBrains нравятся.

Comment: Вроде-бы теперь все в голове уложилось... Но теперь выбор, что использовать для бэкенда nodejs или python